# docker can't run a go output file that already exist

Tags: docker, go, docker-multi-stage-build

I'm building a multi-stage Dockerfile for my go project.

```
FROM golang:latest as builder

COPY ./go.mod /app/go.mod
COPY ./go.sum /app/go.sum

#exporting go1.11 module support variable
ENV GO111MODULE=on

WORKDIR /app/

#create vendor directory
RUN go mod download

COPY . /app/

RUN go mod vendor

#building source code
RUN go build -mod=vendor -o main -v ./src/


FROM alpine:latest
RUN apk --no-cache add ca-certificates
COPY --from=builder /app/main /app/main
WORKDIR /app/

ARG port="80"
ENV PORT=$port
EXPOSE $PORT

CMD ["./main"]
```

When I'm running the image, it throws error:

```
standard_init_linux.go:207: exec user process caused "no such file or directory"
```

I've verified that the 'main' file exist in /app/main.
I also tried to give executable permission by adding

```
chmod +x /app/main
```

but still it doesn't work.
What can possibly be wrong?

Comment: what is your host os ?

Comment: Run Docker with -D option, see if it gives any useful error message.

Comment: Could you please do `RUN ls` before `CMD ["./main"]` and show an output?

Comment: @MostafaHussein It's MacOS.

Also, I tried with `ls` and it did print a long machine code output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "latest" version of the golang image is debian based, which uses libc. Alpine uses musl. If you do not compile with `CGO_ENABLED=0`, networking libraries will link to libc and the no such file or directory error point to a missing library. You can check these shared library links with `ldd /app/main`. A few solutions I can think of:

- compile your program with `CGO_ENABLED=0`
- switch your build image to `FROM golang:alpine`
- change your second stage to be `FROM debian`