# Docker can't start the app when I use alpine base image

Tags: docker

I use `ENTRYPOINT["./app"]` in dockerfile, when I use the other larger image, it was work

But when I used  alpine, it told me `exec ./app: no such file or directory`

And I'm sure the file is exist in container

I'm guess alpine doesn't have bash, so I try to use `RUN apk update && apk add bash`, but it still not work

What's wrong?

Here is my dockerfile:

```
FROM        golang AS build
WORKDIR     /app
COPY        . .
RUN         cd ./src && go build -o ../bin/app
RUN         rm -r src/ .vscode/ .git/

FROM    alpine AS release
COPY    --from=build /app /app

WORKDIR     /app/bin
ENTRYPOINT ["./app"]
```

And this is container content:

[image]

Even I install bash, it still not found

Also I just forgot to say, docker runs on the wsl2

Comment: Can you share the full Dockerfile?

Comment: Alpine doesn't use bash by default: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44803982/how-do-i-run-a-bash-script-in-an-alpine-docker-container

Comment: You're building on a Debian-based image, but trying to run the application on an Alpine-based image.  Does it help to make these distributions line up, as suggested in [docker can't run a go output file that already exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55200508/docker-cant-run-a-go-output-file-that-already-exist)?

Answer (score 0):

You have to investigate the reasons.

I suggest you to put the following lines to inspect the presence of the executable file where you should run it:

```
RUN pwd
RUN ls -l
```